# How to transfer data between Android phone and PC via USB?

Tags: android, data-transfer

**How to transfer data between Android phone and PC via USB?**

As far as I know there is USB Host/Accessory support for Android devices, but will that work for Windows/Linux?

You can also use Sockets. For that you need forward packets via ADB, so how to connect Android app to both Windows and Linux PC?

Is there a way how to make this communication platform independent?

Comment: check this link: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/107

Comment: Which project? Seems to me like they're all targeted only on Arduinos not PCs.

Comment: all of these might be helpful for you, but most useful is probably http://libusb.info/

Comment: A good library with simple GUI sample for Linux could be found here(https://github.com/whoozle/android-file-transfer-linux). At least it works for Android and Windows Phone 8. Btw, this is the only solution which is able to connect my WP and kubuntu via USB. I'm not sure if it'll work for Windows. You can ask the project maintainer - he's quick to help.